# Used rm -r command in OS X and think I screwed something up?

Tags: macos, mac, shell, zsh, osx-el-capitan

So I was installing iterm, brew, zsh and ohmyzsh. Everything was going fine until I started installing ohmyzsh - during the installation I was asked about my password and entered it in a wrong language and the installation abruptly ended. I figured I needed to reinstall ohmyzsh so what I did was write `rm -r .oh-my-zsh` which seemed perfectly legit to me. Instead of just removing the said folder the terminal wrote something like `override --r--r--r` and some long path. I entered `no` and have been prompted with a similar question after which I figured I better close the terminal. What the hell was that and did I screw anything?

Ultimately I figured I needed to write `rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh` to remove the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't screw anything up in this instance.

There were some files in that folder that you did not have write permission for, and `rm` will by default ask you for your permission to delete these, even if you are the owner of them.

To illustrate:

```
$ ls -l a_file
ls: a_file: No such file or directory

$ touch a_file

$ ls -l a_file
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff  0 Jul 30 09:30 a_file

$ chmod -w a_file

$ ls -l a_file
-r--r--r--  1 kk  staff  0 Jul 30 09:30 a_file

$ rm a_file
override r--r--r--  kk/staff for a_file? y

$ ls -l a_file
ls: a_file: No such file or directory
```

When you add `-f` to `rm`, it will assume it has your permission to delete these files.

Answer (score 0):

So what the question? You can't screw up system until you use `sudo` :)
If you just missed your password - you can make `brew uninstall oh-my-zsh`